# Ionic Showing multiple viewes in a single page

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I`m using Ionic to build an application.
I`m new to Ionic and i would like some help in setting up my view.

my app contains an abstract main view which contains the main header

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="main-view">
    <ion-header-bar class='bar bar-header bar-stable' align-title="center">
        <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="View-A"></ion-nav-view>
    <ion-nav-view name="View-B"></ion-nav-view>
</script>
```

and another view which supposed to be like a split screen. basicly i`m trying to show 2 views on the same page (with different controllers)

this is my config:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
      .state('main', {
          url: '/main',
          abstract: true,
          templateUrl: 'main-view'
          }

      })
    .state('main.inner', {
        url: '/inner',
        views: {
            'View-A': {
                templateUrl: "View-A",
                controller: 'ViewACtrl'
            },
            'View-B': {
                templateUrl: 'View-B',
                controller: 'ViewBCtrl'
            }
        }
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main/inner');

})
```

The views look like this

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="View-A">
    <ion-view>
<-- DATA -->
 </ion-view>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="View-B">
    <ion-view>
<-- DATA -->
 </ion-view>
</script>
```

The Problem is, that only the second view is shown.
what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
<ion-nav-view name="View-A"></ion-nav-view>
<ion-nav-view name="View-B"></ion-nav-view>
```

with

```
<div ui-view="View-A"></div>
<div ui-view="View-B"></div>
```

**EDIT**

There is an option to use this [library](https://github.com/alongubkin/ionic-multiple-views/blob/master/demo/js/app.js). Add 'ionicMultipleViews' to angular.module and it should work.

Comment: ion-nav-view holds the history of state transitions and should be used as single parent view. Try ion-view directive instead.

Comment: ok. i've checked this out and found that it's not possible. You can try this extension https://github.com/alongubkin/ionic-multiple-views

Comment: Not possible at all or not bossible using ionic?

Comment: not possible using ionic by default. But it's standard angular practice to use multiple views.

Comment: can you give me an example that will match my case?